# Autoajustar texto en celdas de un ListBox en Access con VBA

Tags: ms-access

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo un ListBox en el cual en 3 columnas cargo datos, el problema es que los datos me salen cortados, hasta cierta longitud, y no he encontrado la forma de autoajustar la celda a la longitud del texto, como se hace en Excel, el problemas es que la información me queda cortada y necesito que se vea, aumentando el alto de la fila para que el texto se ajuste a esa celda y se muestre completo.
Adjunto foto explicativa.
De antemano, gracias por su ayuda.

Espero que me faciliten cuál es la propiedad para que la celda del ListBox se autoajuste al tamaño del texto para que este se muestre en su totalidad.

Mi código carga es ese listBox datos de la BD en Access 2021, uso código VBA, con eso no tengo problema, el problema es que no se muestran completos los datos. El código que hice para actualizar es

```
Sub actuaTabla()
If IsNull(IdTabla) Then
Else
TablaId = IdTabla
TotalPtosExa = contarPtos
LeccAsignadas = contarLecc
ListaObjCont.Requery
End If
ListaObjCont.Requery
End Sub
```

javdromero Gracias por tu respuesta, pero la propiedad HorizontalScrollbar no está disponible para este control, en su lugar me sugiere HorizontalAnchor. Aún no he podido solucionarlo.

Comment: Hola JAM, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar). Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: *Espero que me faciliten un código* No. Esto no es un sitio de pedidos a la carta.  Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, cuando pregunté lo que quise decir era que si sabían cuál era la propiedad, porque he probado varias y no funcionan.

Comment: Gracias Marce Puente. Tu actitud es la mejor

Answer (score 0):

FYI El texto no se corta o trunca, sólo no se muestra. Una alternativa es mostrar el scroll horizontal así siempre mantienes una línea por item sin importar la longitud del texto

```
ListBoxTest.HorizontalScrollbar = True
```

La otra opción es usar varias líneas dependiendo del texto y ancho del listbox. [Tal cual como lo solucionan en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613613/winforms-dotnet-listbox-items-to-word-wrap-if-content-string-width-is-bigger-tha)

Comment: Hola javdromero Gracias por tu respuesta, pero la propiedad HorizontalScrollbar no está disponible para este control, en su lugar me sugiere HorizontalAnchor. Aún no he podido solucionarlo.